# How to auto fill my form just like we get value by serialize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just like with jquery function `serialize()` we can get all the values of form how can I set all value to form ?

```js
function getAllValue(){
    document.write($("#test").serialize());
}

function setAllValue(){
    var all_values = [{name:"input1",value:"test1"},{name:"input2",value:"test2"},{name:"input3",value:"test3"}];
    $.map(all_values,function(input) {
        $("input[name='"+input.name+"']").val(input.value);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
  <input type="text" name="input1">
  <input type="text" name="input2">
  <input type="text" name="input3">
  <input type="button" onClick="getAllValue();" value="Get All Value">
  <input type="button" onClick="setAllValue();" value="Set All Value">
</form>
```

Or this is also a good solution which I am doing right now. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more generic, something that you can use even if you don't know what inputs the form will have, you can use this:

```
var inputsNamesArray = $("#test").serialize().replace(/\=[^\=\&]*/g,"").split("&");
$.each(inputsNamesArray, function(key,val){
    $("#test input[name="+val+"]").val("placeholder");
});
```